# WooCommerce display product categories within custom taxonomy archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I made a custom taxonomy for Wordpress called "Brand", and assigned it to Products post type. Great! Now all my products can be differentiated on a higher order. The archive page for brand is copied from product-archive.php so each brand has an archive page. Great still!

So, a product can now have two taxonomies:

```
Product Brand: Nike
Standard Product Category: Outerwear
```

The structure is set up like so:

```
mysite.com/brand/nike/
mysite.com/product-category/outerwear
```

Here is where the issue comes in: If you are on a Brand Archive page and click a standard product category, "outerware", it correctly brings you back to the outerware category archive for ALL brands. I need to be able to click a product category "outerware" and stay within the Nike brand page.

The obvious/built-in solution i thought of was making Brands a hierarchical taxonomy, so each brand would have children categories.

```
mysite.com/brand/category/outerware
```

This solves my display/filtering problem and the url structure I proposed above works great.

But this poses a huge problem because then each Brand would have duplicate categories, ie. Nike would have "outerware" and Adidas would have "outerware" as children categories. This doesn't make sense - I need all "outerware" to be within the same category, not split up between brands.

Another half solution: Create custom templates for each brand page, and on the sidebar of each brand have a custom menu built that calls specific queries. So on the Nike page, i would have a link called Outerware which goes to a page that queries Nike and Outerware - but this will quickly become unmanageable once we add tons of products.

In a nutshell, I need to be querying/filtering a standard woocommerce product category within a custom taxonomy. So the logic would be:

```
on BRAND archive page, click WOOCOMMERCE CATEGORY and
display WOOCOMMERCE CATEGORY for only that BRAND
```

Thank you! This to me is a fun logic problem to solve - but I just cant get the answer.

Comment: This is a much harder problem to solve than you might think, not due to the DB query (that's easy), but due to the *permalinks*.

Comment: Ok hm. So consider this. WooCommerce Attributes lets you do this. It lets you "Filter" within a result set. WooCommerce attributes are just custom taxonomies, so I feel there should be some sort of code to allow a custom taxonomy to act as a Product attribute. Thanks!

Comment: I said that part is easy.  The part that is hard is getting your *permalinks* to work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help. Do i understand correctly that you mean that the URL will need to look like this something like: /?filtering=1&filter_min-kvadratura=181&filter_max-kvadratura=108&filter_obem-ohlajdane=111

Comment: I have a similar problem. Cross filtration by category and brand. how was your above issue resolved? Currently I'm using 'Perfect Brands for WooCommerce' which has a great widget for filter brands WITHIN a category (URL ?pwd-brand=xxxx) but I need the reverse of this. i.e. if someone filters by a brand within a category then only show subcategories with a product in them (effectively hiding categories that don't have products for the Category + brand taxonomy combination...)